# fetchall() возвращает пустой список. Python, sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Не могу сообразить, как работать с `fetchall`, `fetchone` в `sqlite3`.

Вот у меня функция, которая вытаскивает из бд статистику за один день:

```py
def get_day_statistics():
    statistics = cursor.execute(f"SELECT created, "
                                f"(SELECT name "
                                f"FROM categories "
                                f"WHERE expences.category_codename = categories.codename) AS name, "
                                f"SUM(amount) AS amount "
                                f"FROM expences "
                                f"WHERE created = {str(date.today())} "
                                f"GROUP BY name "
                                f"ORDER BY amount DESC;")
    fetch = statistics.fetchall()
    print(fetch)
    return fetch
```

В `DB Browser` запрос срабатывает как положенно и возвращает мне именно то, что я хочу.
Следуя логике, выполняю `execute` с этим запросом и ловлю ответ с помощью `fetchall()`. Но получаю пустой список.
Где я туплю, ребят?

Comment: Скорее всего тут проблема `f"WHERE created = {str(date.today())} "`, замените на связываемую переменную. Ищите пример по "parameter substitution" в https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Я пробовал `date.today`  заменять на внутренний sql таймштамп `date('now')`. Результат тот же. Проблема не в нем.

Comment: Вы, очевидно, не поняли суть моего комментария. Проблема в том, что вы делает подстановку в строку. Это плохо само по себе, но в том числе это создает проблему тут. Используйте parameter  substibution, для того что передавать параметры.

Comment: Бегло избавился от запроса `date`. Теперь массив заполнен данными. Вы правы, проблема здесь. Сейчас нужно сломать голову вопросом, как составить кортеж параметров? Или можно как-то прямо по месту определить параметр в конкретном месте?

Comment: Не понятно, что спрашиваете. Задайте новый вопрос с деталями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы делает подстановку в строку в этом месте `f"WHERE created = {str(date.today())}`.

Это плохо само по себе, но в том числе это создает проблему тут. Питон форматирует дату так, что sqlite не понимает переданный формат. Замените на связываемую переменную (англ. [parameter substibution](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)):

```
statistics = cursor.execute(f"SELECT created, "
                            f"(SELECT name "
                            f"FROM categories "
                            f"WHERE expences.category_codename = categories.codename) AS name, "
                            f"SUM(amount) AS amount "
                            f"FROM expences "
                            f"WHERE created = ? "
                            f"GROUP BY name "
                            f"ORDER BY amount DESC;", (date.today(),))
```